# Collection was mutated while being enumerated - everything is synchronized and not mutated while iterating

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, iteration

I am not an Objective C expert, and the issue occurs with a code that I didn't wrote.
However, I did a research and could not find what can be a possible root case for my problem.
(I have a good understanding in multi-threaded programming in Java and C/C++).

Below is an [obscured] version of the code that throws the exception (which ends up with a crash):

```
@interface someInterface ()
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *activeTokens;
```

---

Below function throws the Exception:

```
@implementation someInterface

- (void)foo:(NSURL*)url headers:(NSDictionary*)headers
{
    @synchronized (self.activeTokens) {
        for (NSValue *object in self.activeTokens) {
            X *tokenObject = object.nonretainedObjectValue;
            if (tokenObject && [tokenObject.a.b isEqualToString:url.absoluteString]) {
                tokenObject.x = [headers objectForKey:@"somekey"];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additional functions that access the collection:

```
- (X*)bar:(NSURL*)url protocol:(NSString*)str 
{


    X *token = [[X alloc] ...];
    @synchronized (_activeTokens){
        if (!_activeTokens) {
            _activeTokens = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:token];
        [_activeTokens addObject:value];
    }

    ...
}


- (void)releaseToken:(X*)token
{
    NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:token];
    @synchronized(_activeTokens) {
        [_activeTokens removeObject:value];
    }
}



- (X*)getRequestToken:(R*)request
{
    @synchronized (self.activeTokens) {
        for (NSValue *object in self.activeTokens) {
            X *tokenObject = object.nonretainedObjectValue;
            if (tokenObject && [tokenObject.a isEqualToString:[request.headers objectForKey:@"someKey"]]) {
                return tokenObject;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)foooo:(BOOL)success reason:(NSString *)reason
{

    if (!success)
    {
        @synchronized (self.activeTokens) {
            for (NSValue *object in self.activeTokens) {
                X *tokenObject = object.nonretainedObjectValue;
                [tokenObject.s setR:reason];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that I can think about is a scenario when the activeToken is nil while synchronizing on it - but I think this shouldn't be a problem, should it?

UPD:
After investigation and conversation in comments, I think that the only scenario is really when the object is still nil so no synchronization occurs.

Here is the implementation of synchronization by Apple:

```
BREAKPOINT_FUNCTION(
    void objc_sync_nil(void)
);


// Begin synchronizing on 'obj'. 
// Allocates recursive mutex associated with 'obj' if needed.
// Returns OBJC_SYNC_SUCCESS once lock is acquired.  
int objc_sync_enter(id obj)
{
    int result = OBJC_SYNC_SUCCESS;

    if (obj) {
        SyncData* data = id2data(obj, ACQUIRE);
        require_action_string(data != NULL, done, result = OBJC_SYNC_NOT_INITIALIZED, "id2data failed");

        result = recursive_mutex_lock(&data->mutex);
        require_noerr_string(result, done, "mutex_lock failed");
    } else {
        // @synchronized(nil) does nothing
        if (DebugNilSync) {
            _objc_inform("NIL SYNC DEBUG: @synchronized(nil); set a breakpoint on objc_sync_nil to debug");
        }
        objc_sync_nil();
    }

done: 
    return result;
}
```

We can see that nothing happens when synchronizing on nil.

I will move the allocation of the array to the initializer.

Comment: It's hard to get an NSMutableArray behave nicely in a multithreaded environment. I would suggest to use an NSArray instead and handle a mutableCopy when needed. It would also be good to dispatch your success part to the same thread which handles the _activeTokens (using GCD).

Comment: @JTea thanks for your comment. But what do you mean by saying it is "hard" ? Is it possible? What is wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Means, i've run into similar issues using NSMutableArray. A @synchronized(nil) could indeed be a problem.Did you try to alloc the array in the class init method?

Answer (score 1):

A "brute force" solution would be to iterate using the ++ method, that is:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.activeTokens.count; i++)
  {
  NSValue *object = [self.activeTokens objectAtIndex:i];
  //...
  }
```

Comment: I expected for such answer, but I can't understand why it should apply in this case, since I can't see a modification here while iterating. Do I miss something?

Comment: I agree with you. I can't see why it should cause this crash.

Comment: Probably because initially the pointer in NIL and no actual synchronization occurs? And then, the array is allocated while already performing the iteration function...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the collection object is nil in the beginning, and the allocation is lazy (when first adding). This is wrong since synchronize on nil does nothing - see updates in the question.